# Python Tkinter threading button command and main loop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter, keylogger

I am making a keylogger(for educational purposes only) using Tkinter and I tried to implement threading so when I press the button, the keylogger would run while still running the root.mainloop().

The code is:

```
import keylogger
import time
from Tkinter import *
import threading

now = time.time()
done = lambda: time.time() < now + -1

def print_keys(modifiers, keys): print "%r   %r" % (keys, modifiers)  

def key():
    sys.stdout = open('keylogger.txt', 'w')
    keylogger.log(done, print_keys)

def keystop():
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.exit()

def loop():
    root.mainloop()

def ft():
    pt = threading.Thread(target = key)
    ct = threading.Thread(target = loop)
    pt.start()
    ct.start()


root = Tk()
button1 = Button(root, text = "Start", command = ft)
button1.pack()

button2 = Button(root, text = "Stop", command = keystop)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If all you're doing is logging keys, why do you think you need to use threads? Also, what exactly is your question. You've told us what you want, and you've shown some code. What do you need help with?

Comment: I need to properly implement threading and I need to do that because whenever I start the keylogger, the Tkinter GUI just froze therefore I cannot stop it without forcing the script to quit.

Comment: That sounds like you simply didn't know how to properly implement a periodic function in Tkinter, not like you need threading. Moreover, you're calling mainloop twice in this code, which you should never do.

Comment: I've added the loop function because I thought the keylogger, when started, the current mainloop will be broken.